# SWIFT slide one Object "in and out"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

Is there a way to animate an object in swift (UIView, UIButton, etc.) so that it slides out on the left side of the screen and slides in at the same time on the right side of the screen, that the parts of f.e. an UIView that already slided out on the left side are already sliding in again from the right side.
I hope you can understand my question, its a bit tricky to explain this problem. 
I'm using Xcode + Swift 3.0.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> that the parts of f.e. an UIView that already slided out on the left side are already sliding in again from the right side

This almost slipped by me. The only way you have one "view" appear in two places on a screen is by really having two views, one on the left and one on the right.

Then, you could set the widthAnchors (properly), hide the subviews (properly), and animate. If the animation is fast enough (my one-sided slide out is set for 0.3 seconds) the user would think it's all one view.

Comment: In short, the answer is "No, you can't do that." You have to fake it by having 2 identical-looking views, one that's sliding off-screen and the second that's sliding on-screen at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIView.animate()`. Trigger a second animation after the first has completed.

Possible implementation to get the idea:

```
var container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0))
view.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
container.addSubview(view)
let screenWidth = CGFloat(356.0)

// animate to left
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
    view.center = CGPoint(x: -view.frame.size.width, y: view.frame.origin.y)
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
    //set view to right of screen
    view.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width + screenWidth, y: view.frame.origin.y)

    // animate back to center
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        view.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    })

})
```